# Python string templater

Tags: python, ruby, templates, string

I'm using this REST web service, which returns various templated strings as urls, for example:

```
"http://api.app.com/{foo}"
```

In Ruby, I can then use

```
url = Addressable::Template.new("http://api.app.com/{foo}").expand('foo' => 'bar')
```

to get

```
"http://api.app.com/bar"
```

Is there any way to do this in Python? I know about %() templates, but obviously they're not working here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a quick hack.

What is used there (and implemented by Addressable) are [URI Templates](http://bitworking.org/projects/URI-Templates/spec/draft-gregorio-uritemplate-03.html). There seem to be several libs for this in python, for example: [uri-templates](http://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/). [described_routes_py](http://github.com/asplake/described_routes-py/tree/master) also has a parser for them.

Answer (score 4):

In python 2.6 you can do this if you need exactly that syntax

```
from string import Formatter
f = Formatter()
f.format("http://api.app.com/{foo}", foo="bar")
```

If you need to use an earlier python version then you can either copy the 2.6 formatter class or hand roll a parser/regex to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a perfect solution but you could try using `string.Template`.
You either pre-process your incoming URL and then use string.Template directly, like

```
In [6]: url="http://api.app.com/{foo}"
In [7]: up=string.Template(re.sub("{", "${", url))
In [8]: up.substitute({"foo":"bar"})
Out[8]: 'http://api.app.com/bar'
```

taking advantage of the default "${...}" syntax for replacement identifiers. Or you subclass `string.Template` to control the identifier pattern, like

```
class MyTemplate(string.Template):
    delimiter = ...
    pattern   = ...
```

but I haven't figured that out.